# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'album_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, seeding

I want to link multiple images to multiple albums. I got the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'album_id' doesn't have a default value

I don't want to have a default value for my album_id.

My fotos table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fotos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('album_id');
    });
}
```

My album table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->string('naam');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My pivot table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('album_foto', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('album_id');
        $table->integer('foto_id');
    });
}
```

My albums table seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Album;

class AlbumsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
```

First album

```
public function run() {

  $album = new Album([

        'foto' => 'Vlinder.jpg',
        'naam' => 'Black & White'
    ]);
    $album->save();
```

Second album

```
  $album = new Album([

        'foto' => 'Waterval2.jpg',
        'naam' => 'Mother Nature'
    ]);
    $album->save();
 }
}
```

My fotos table seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Foto;

class FotosTableSeeder extends Seeder {
```

Images first album

```
 public function run() {

  $foto = new Foto([
            'foto' => 'Vlinder.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Berlijn.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Mist.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Mystery_Guy.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Pop.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Pop2.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Pop3.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Spiegel.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Stammen.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Voet.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Vogels.jpg'
        ]
    );
    $foto->save();
```

Images second album

```
   $foto = new Foto([
            'foto' => 'Maan.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Plant.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Sneeuw.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Stammen.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Steen.JPG'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Vlinder.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'foto' => 'Vogels.jpg'
        ]
    );
    $foto->save();
 }
}
```

Comment: Make it nullable: `$table->integer('album_id')->nullable();`

Comment: It sounds like you want a many to many relationship between images and albums. You are going to need one more table: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: It doesn't resolve it. When I click on the album, I want to have all the images from that album.

Comment: @adam, I already have a pivot table, 'album_foto'

Comment: Why do you have `album_id`on the `fotos` table?

Comment: The album_id is a foreign key from the album table.
I must have a one-to-many and a many-to-many relationship

Comment: Yes I can see that, but why do you need it if you already have a many-to-many relationship between the two tables? Regardless, as adam suggested just make it `nullable` if you want fotos without an album.

Comment: @Remul, it's a project for someone. The person wants to have a one-to-many and a many-to-many relationship

Comment: In my fotos table, I have NULL in the column 'album_id'. That's not what I want. I want the id from the album.

Comment: If you don't want a null, you need to supply it the album id.

Comment: How do you mean supply? I don't understand

Comment: Can someone help me please? I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Use unsigned column definition for bind foreign keys to ids.

Define also foreign keys to connect your tables properly.

Try to declare your table in this way:

```
<?php
// Fotos table 
public function up() {
    Schema::create('fotos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->integer('album_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');
    });
}

// Album table
public function up() {
    Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->string('naam');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

// Pivot table
public function up() {
    Schema::create('album_foto', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('foto_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');
        $table->foreign('foto_id')->references('id')->on('fotos');
    });
}
```